# How to catch error of specific router request before it ends up in global error handler

Tags: node.js, express, error-handling, routes

So my routes are ordered like shown bellow

verifyToken middleware is being used in a lot of routes.
Generally if an error occurs i want the global error handler of index.js to handle it.

But if the error occurred while verifyToken middleware is being used by the login.html route with method = get i would like
to handle it inside routers/user.js which i thought i could do by using `router.get(/\/login(\.html)?$/, (error, req, res, next) => {}` but the error bypasses it and moves to global error handler.

index.js

```
const userRouter = require('./routers/user')

app.get('', (req, res) => {
    res.render('index')
})

app.use(userRouter)

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.status(404).redirect('/404.html');
})

//Global error handling
app.use( (error, req, res, next) => {
 switch(error.name) {
        case "UnauthorizedError":
            console.log("UnauthorizedError = ", error.message)
            res.status(401).redirect('/401.html');
            break
        case "InternalServerError":
            console.log("InternalServerError = ", error.message)
            res.status(500).send('whatever')
            break
        default:
            console.log("Another error = ", error)
    }
})
```

/routers/user.js

```
const verifyToken = require('../middleware/authentication/verifyToken')

router.get(/\/login(\.html)?$/, verifyToken, (req, res) => {
    // If he is already logged in redirect him to dashboard
    // This route works as expected
    res.redirect('/admin/dashboard.html')
});

router.get(/\/login(\.html)?$/, (error, req, res, next) => {
    // If error = Unauthorized
    // which means that he is not logged in proceed
    if(error.name === 'UnauthorizedError') res.render('login')
    // else pass error to global error handler (at index.js)
    else next(error)
});

module.exports = router
```

/middleware/authentication/verifyToken.js

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')
var createError = require('http-errors')

const verifyToken = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        // Do some stuff
        if (token_doesnt_exist) return next(createError(401, 'TOKEN NOT FOUND', {expose: false}))
        // Do some stuff
        next()
    } catch {
        next(createError(e.status, e.message, {expose: false}))
    }
})

module.exports = verifyToken
```

**UPDATE**

I ended up transforming

`router.get(/\/login(\.html)?$/, (error, req, res, next) => {}`

to

`router.use((error, req, res, next) => {}`

which i guess works since it only catches errors from the above route.
I'm not sure if this is the best way i'd really like to see an alternative.

```
const verifyToken = require('../middleware/authentication/verifyToken')

router.get(/\/login(\.html)?$/, verifyToken, (req, res) => {
    // If he is already logged in redirect him to dashboard
    // This route works as expected
    res.redirect('/admin/dashboard.html')
});

router.use((error, req, res, next) => {
    // If error = Unauthorized
    // which means that he is not logged in proceed
    if(error.name === 'UnauthorizedError') res.render('login')
    // else pass error to global error handler (at index.js)
    else next(error)
});

module.exports = router
```

Comment: Express routes do not have callback signature of `(error, req, res, next)` afaik, its only `(req, res, next)`. If you want to handle error at login/verifyToken level, do not call the `next()` which'll invoke global middleware/error handler that u are using. Instead throw the error or handle there itself, if that's what you intend.

Comment: @Pimento Web Yeah! At global middleware level (express comes with it, at bottom of middleware stack) like OP is using yes u can I know that. Not sure if one can use the same signature with routes callbacks.. that's what I intended to say.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to catch errors ONLY in that route you can catch the error in the middleware itself:

```
const verifyToken = async (req, res, next) => {
   try {
      //middleware logic
   } catch(err) {
      //error handling logic
   }
```

Maybe not SUPER elegant but it works..